# What is the best way to implement restful routing in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, routes

Missing my Rails map.resources and wondering how I can implement something similar in ASP.NET MVC 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Simply Restful Routing](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting&referringTitle=Documentation&ProjectName=mvccontrib) and if you want to handle different formats this [blog post](http://fatagnus.com/how-to-serve-the-same-data-in-json-xml-or-html-with-aspnet-mvc/) is worth checking.